# Using cursor to insert data from on table to another but inserting only first row

Tags: sql, while-loop, database-cursor, mssql-jdbc

there are 2 table (capacitymaster2 , #CapacityInsertData) I want to check some condition and insert to capacitymaster2 .

Note : #CapacityInsertData has 3 row where all data satisfies the condition inside the while loops

when i test all the data are displaying 1 by 1 using select (3 times loop)
when i uncomment insert statement insert happens only once first row, but loops correctly goes 3 times with right data

```
DECLARE @RowNum INT;
    DECLARE @Category VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @PlantCode VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @SubCategory VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @SizeRange VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @Capacity VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @CreatedBy VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @CreatedOn VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @count INT = 1
    DECLARE @max_count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #CapacityInsertData)

    DECLARE Material_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR SELECT [Category],
                [PlantCode],
                [SubCategory],
                [SizeRange],
                [Capacity],
                [CreatedBy],
                [CreatedOn]
    FROM #CapacityInsertData;

    OPEN Material_CURSOR;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Material_CURSOR 
    INTO @Category
        , @PlantCode
        , @SubCategory
        , @SizeRange
        , @Capacity
        , @CreatedBy
        , @CreatedOn;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @count <= @max_count
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Category,SubCategory  FROM ProductCategoryMapping2 WHERE trim(Category) = trim(@Category) AND trim(SubCategory)=trim(@SubCategory))
            BEGIN
                IF EXISTS (SELECT Plantcode from PlantMaster2 WHERE trim(Plantcode)=trim(@PlantCode))
                BEGIN
                        IF EXISTS( SELECT SizeRange from  SizeRangeMaster WHERE trim(SizeRange)= trim(@SizeRange))
                            BEGIN
                                
                                if NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #CapacityInsertData 
                                    WHERE trim(Category) + '_' + trim(SubCategory) + '_' + trim(PlantCode) + '_' + trim(SizeRange)
                                        IN (SELECT trim(Category) + '_' + trim(SubCategory) + '_' + trim(PlantCode) + '_' + trim(SizeRange) FROM CapacityMaster2))
                                BEGIN
                                    INSERT INTO CapacityMaster2([Category],
                                            [PlantCode],
                                            [SubCategory],
                                            [SizeRange],
                                            [Capacity],
                                            [CreatedBy],
                                            [CreatedOn]) 
                                            Values( @Category
                                                    , @PlantCode
                                                    , @SubCategory
                                                    , @SizeRange
                                                    , @Capacity
                                                    , @CreatedBy
                                                    , GETDATE())

                                    
                                END 
                        END
                END
        END
        --select @count
        SET @count = @count + 1 
        select @Category, @PlantCode, @SubCategory, @SizeRange, @Capacity, @CreatedBy, @CreatedOn
        FETCH NEXT FROM Material_CURSOR INTO @Category
                                        , @PlantCode
                                        , @SubCategory
                                        , @SizeRange
                                        , @Capacity
                                        , @CreatedBy
                                        , @CreatedOn;
            
    END
     
                                            
    

    CLOSE Material_CURSOR;
    DEALLOCATE Material_CURSOR;
```

I tried several ways changing fetch positions , all data was expected while debugging (select statement) ,

i need all satisfied record to be inserted into capacitymaster2 from CapacityInsertData

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with the layout of the cursor, if you stick a PRINT statement right before the INSERT that should prove if it's failing on your IF statements which is more likely